# Unable to Upload Image

Tags: support, images

I am attempting to upload a couple screengrabs to an Answer, and no matter which image I try to upload (tried on multiple computers and multiple browsers), it looks like what's below.

Looking online, I can't find any explanation for this behavior.  The post I'm having a problem with is below.  Mine is the latest answer.

[Constructing a Seismic Tripartite Graph with TikZ & pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308907/constructing-a-seismic-tripartite-graph-with-tikz-pgfplots/579560#579560)

[image]

Comment: It does, thanks.  I couldn't find any mention of it being an network-wide issue, so apologies for double-posting a similar bug report.